# How to get played songs with swift

Tags: ios, swift, media-player

I want to know when a song is played on music app and get its info. But I don't want to get all songs from library, It's just the songs that was played since the app starts to scan.

It's like you play something, then you open the app and it scan what you played.

I've searching about this but didn't find nothing, and I don't know where to start to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

First, add the `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` key to your `Info.plist` with a description of why you need access to the user's media library

Then you can find all songs that have been played since a certain time with the following code:

```
import MediaPlayer

@IBAction func getSongs(_ sender: Any) {
    let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))!

    // Check for permissions        
    switch MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorized, .restricted:
        fetchSongPlayed(since: yesterday)
    case .notDetermined:
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { _ in
            let auth = MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus()
            if auth == .authorized || auth == .restricted {
                self.fetchSongPlayed(since: yesterday)
            }
        }
    case .denied:
        print("No access to the Media Library")
    }
}

func fetchSongPlayed(since date: Date) {
    let query = MPMediaQuery.songs()
    var results = [MPMediaItem]()

    if let songs = query.items {
        results = songs.filter { ($0.lastPlayedDate ?? Date.distantPast) > date }
    } else {
        print("Can't fetch songs")
    }

    // Now do whatever you want with results
    // It's an array of MPMediaItem
    print(results.count)
}
```

One more tip: sync some music from iTunes to your device as the Simulator doesn't have any bye default. There's [a way to add it](https://maikohermans.github.io/2016/12/28/ios-use-music-library-with-simulator) to the simulator but it's just easier to test on device.

Comment: It's working perfectly, but there's a problem: if I played a song more than one time the `results` array still contains just one time that song.